# Store string in array

Tags: c++

I created a function to store a string in an array without spaces and punctuation:

```
int main()
{
    char arr[1];int b,i=0;
    bool newl = false;
    for(;!newl;)
    {
        arr[i]=cin.get();
        b = arr[i];
        if(b>=65&&b<=90) i++;
        else if(b>=97&&b<=122) i++;
        if(arr[i]=='\n') newl =true;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
    cout << arr[j];
}
```

it seemed pretty logic to me but when i tested it, its behaviour didnt turn out as i expected like with 1 character its ok but more than that its just really wrong.Is it because of the cin.get? Sorry im newb.
Thanks.

Comment: Why `arr` have a size of 1 then?

Comment: No need for the integers, you can actually use like `if (b > 'a')`, of course, char b;

Comment: i thought c++ doesnt have any bound checking so i just put 1 in there.            @Joel i dont get you.i wanted to check whether its the alphabet (and CAP form ofc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocated only one element to `arr`, so accessing `arr[1]` or further is forbidden.

`std::vector` is useful as variable-length array.

Also I suggest you should use `isalpha()` from library `cctype` instead of the comparation against magic numbers that are relatively hard to understand and dependent on the character code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> arr;int b,i=0;
    bool newl = false;
    for(;!newl;)
    {
        b = cin.get(); // store the input directly into b
        if(isalpha(b)) arr.push_back(b);
        if(b=='\n') newl = true;
    }
    for(size_t j=0;j<arr.size();j++)
        cout << arr[j];
}
```

Comment: Ooops thats a stupid mistake.Thanks for the advice but i thought C++ doesnt have any bound checking so why does it have now ?